# SUMIF doesn't work with nested MONTH or LEFT function

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm started with the following:

```
=SUMIF(MONTH('Inventory'!K:K),B5,'Inventory'!M:M)
```

where `MONTH('Inventory'!K:K)` is supposed to return the month number (Jan=1, Feb=2, etc.) from a mm/dd/yyyy date column, B5 holds the month number I want to sum by, and `'Inventory'!M:M` is an amount column.

In place of `MONTH('Inventory'!K:K)` I also tried `LEFT('Inventory'!K:K, 1)` with no luck.

I though possibly that the MONTH expression is returning a value where Excel is looking for a Range, but I wasn't able to find a workaround. Tried the following, which also didn't work:

```
=SUMIF('Inventory'!K:K,MONTH('Inventory'!K:K)=B5,'Inventory'!M:M)
```

While a pivot could work, I wanted the user to be able to just add to the Inventory tab without worrying about refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

Create start and end dates from the numerical month in B5 rather than trying to convert the dates in column K to numerical month integers.

```
=SUMIFS('Inventory'!M:M, 'Inventory'!K:K, ">="&date(2017, B5, 1), 'Inventory'!K:K, "<"&date(2017, B5+1, 1))
```

Note SUMIFS, not SUMIF; they have a slightly different syntax.

Alternately, use SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Inventory'!K:K)=B5)*('Inventory'!M:M))
```

You should trim down the full column references with SUMPRODUCT or be prepared to suffer calculation lag.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Inventory'!K2:index('Inventory'!K:K, match(1e99, 'Inventory'!K:K)))=B5)*('Inventory'!M2:index('Inventory'!M:M, match(1e99, 'Inventory'!K:K))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you need, but here are two options that don't restrict you to one year's worth of months:

1) Create a helper column next to `'Inventory'!K:K` to extract the month, then write your `SUMIF` using that column as the range.

2) Use `SUMPRODUCT` like so:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Inventory'!K:K)=B5)*'Inventory'!M:M)
```